# Code Fragment mode in Pycharm 3 debugging returns None always

Tags: debugging, pycharm

When in debug mode in Pycharm, the `Evaluate Expression -> Code Fragment` tool doesn't seem to be able to assign and display a variable in one go. The only case that seems to be evaluated correctly is when the first line is a constant value.

eg.

```
10
```

results as expected in

```
result = {int} 10
```

but when trying to obtain the same result with:

```
c = 10
c
```

the output is

```
result = {NoneType} None
```

However, if I hover over each variable in fragment window, the values are shown as a popup.

Comment: The problem also appears when having a comment in the first line and an expression in the socond line. Solution: delete the comment or move it behind the expression

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Edits** to sum up the comments (thanks Vaibhav Mishra):

Unfortunately, this seems to be the default behavior: ([won't fix bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11210))

My understanding of this feature:

Although Pycharm will display a `None result` when evaluating multiple lines, they are **all executed** in the context of the currently selected stack frame. One of the consequences being the update of the namespace. Subsequently using single-line evaluations in the same context (or mouse hover) will display the expected values.

Two potential usages:

1. The `Evaluate Code Fragment` dialog is automatically prompted when evaluating multiple lines from the editor: `Select a block | Evaluate Expression (Alt+F8)`. May be useful to tweak a couple of lines and run evaluation in one go.
2. As an alternative to the `Debug Command Line`, the code fragment mode supports loops and if/else. Although the inspection seems a bit tipsy (mistakenly unresolved variables), it can be ignored, and the editing assistance provided there can be put to good use.

Comment: however the bug is a won't fix , apparently this is expected behaviour, thanks for clarification

Comment: The comment also mentions the `Debug Command Line`, which seems to be a good way to make your example work.

Comment: Can anyone shown an example of how to use "Evaluate Expression" in "Code Fragment Mode"?

Comment: @KoliberServices I suppose you evaluate the expression as usual and hover over the individual variables to know their values.

Comment: You can also put `print` statements in the code fragment and the result will be printed to the debug console (not the Evaluate dialog Result pane :( )